# Why do bonds with a shorter next call dates have shorter extension risk?

Tags: options, fixed-income, bond, callable-bonds

I was reading a research article and I'm not really understanding why. Is it to do with the option premium being priced in at the beginning?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the article for context? It would be helpful to know exactly what type of bond your asking about?

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry, this is an article written by a bank so it has restricted access. I'm talking about a standard callable fixed-coupon bond with fixed maturity. In this case, it's a municipal bond.